# How to import JUnit 5 source to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I found some issues regarding taking JUnit5 (https://github.com/junit-team/junit5) inside my Eclipse IDE.

PS: I am using JDK 11 with correctly configured environment files in Windows 10. The same was done inside Eclipse.

I've done the steps:

- Fork to my github and clone it to my local machine.
- Using git bash entered project folder and ./gradlew clean build. Until this part everything went OK and completed sucessfully.
- Open Eclipse and imported as Gradle project.
- After syncing Eclipse workspace, I've got the errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type ArbitraryNamingKotlinTestCase
>   cannot be resolved to a
>   type  AtypicalJvmMethodNameTests.java /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   34    Java Problem InstancePerClassKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   38    Java Problem InstancePerClassKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   43    Java Problem InstancePerClassKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   44    Java Problem InstancePerClassKotlinTestCase cannot be resolved to a
>   type  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   37    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   55    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   60    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   64    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   67    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   70    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   74    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be resolved to
>   a
>   type  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   54    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be resolved to
>   a
>   type  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   65    Java Problem InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot be resolved to
>   a
>   type  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   66    Java Problem METHOD_NAME cannot be resolved to a
>   variable  AtypicalJvmMethodNameTests.java /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   39    Java Problem METHOD_NAME cannot be resolved to a
>   variable  AtypicalJvmMethodNameTests.java /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   40    Java Problem The import
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.kotlin.ArbitraryNamingKotlinTestCase cannot
>   be
>   resolved  AtypicalJvmMethodNameTests.java /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   16    Java Problem The import
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.kotlin.ArbitraryNamingKotlinTestCase cannot
>   be
>   resolved  AtypicalJvmMethodNameTests.java /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   19    Java Problem The import
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.kotlin.InstancePerClassKotlinTestCase cannot
>   be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   21    Java Problem The import
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.kotlin.InstancePerMethodKotlinTestCase cannot
>   be
>   resolved  TestInstanceLifecycleKotlinTests.java   /junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine    line
>   22    Java Problem

It looks like It is not recognizing some Kotlin class files built-in the project. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse IDE does not support compilation of Kotlin source code by default.

To get this working in Eclipse you will need to install the [Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/kotlin-plugin-eclipse) and then right-click on the `junit-jupiter-engine` project and select "Configure Kotlin / Add Kotlin Nature".

Please note, however, that *Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse* has been known **not** to work consistently in Eclipse. Thus, you may simply want to ignore those compiler errors (which is *embarrassingly* what I actually do) or switch to IntelliJ IDEA.